# Clarification of `assoc` syntax in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to use `assoc` in racket to create a memo table and want to associate an ordered pair (x,y) with a value but I am a little unclear of the syntax.

For example I have:

```
[f (lambda (x y)
               (let ([ans (assoc [x y] memo)])
```

But it is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`assoc`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assoc%29%29) procedure receives as its first parameter the "key" to the element that you're looking for, and as second parameter a list of associations - in this context, an *association* is just a key-value pair. It will return the first association that corresponds to the given key or `#f` if none was found. For example:

```
(assoc 'x '((a 1) (b 2) (x 3) (c 4)))
> '(x 3)
```

If you need to use pairs as keys, that's fine and it will work like this:

```
(assoc (list 1 2) '(((1 2) x) ((3 4) y)))
> '((1 2) x)
```

Comment: Of course, if what you intend to do is using a pair of values as the "key" part of an association, that's fine. This works: `(assoc '(1 2) '(((1 2) x) ((3 4) y)))` => `'((1 2) x)`

Answer (score 3):

To add, in professional-level Racket, you may also use [hash tables](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html) to build a lookup table.

```
 (define table (make-hash))
 (hash-set! table 'password "location-of-treasure")
 (printf "Where is the treasure?  ~s\n" (hash-ref table 'password))
```